# Segueing from multiple cells doesn't work the way that it should

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableView that the user can input and delete cells from. Clicking on one of these cells, it takes the user to the view associated to that cell. But when a cell is deleted and all the rows move up by one, the view controller doesn't move. So say you delete Row 2, then row 3 moves up to row 2's spot and has the same view controller as row 2, instead of the original 3's view.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

var selectedRow : Int = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        selectedRow = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowDetail", sender: self)

    }
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? FavouritesViewController {
            destination.row = selectedRow

        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

            //MARK:- remove cell core data
           let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // force unwrapping is perfectly fine

           // 1
           let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            managedContext.delete(self.favourites[indexPath.row])
            self.favourites.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            let impactFeedbackgenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
            impactFeedbackgenerator.prepare()
            impactFeedbackgenerator.impactOccurred()
        }
    }

func insertNewCell() {
     guard save(name: addNewMemory.text!) else { return }
     let indexPath = IndexPath(row: favourites.count - 1, section: 0)
     tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
     addNewMemory.text = ""
     view.endEditing(true)
 }
```

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FavouritesViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

var titleName: [NSManagedObject] = []
var titleString: String = ""
var row: Int!

@IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        titleString = textField.text!
        UserDefaults.standard.set(titleString, forKey: String(row))
        print("Saved")
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: String(row)) != nil {

            textField.text = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: String(row)) as? String
        }
}
```

I expect the view for each cell to stay the same even if another cell is added or removed.

Comment: Are you reloading the tableview with `tableView.reloadData()` after deletion?

Comment: Yes, I am reloading the tableview

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the cell at row 2, the cell that was at row 3 is now the cell at row 2, so when you select it, that's the row you get.

You don't show the code where you delete the cell - in there, you should also be deleting the appropriate item from your model. In your case, that's quite complicated because you're saving strings in user defaults keyed by an index number, so to reflect deletion you need to move every other item in defaults to reflect the new index.

It would be easier for you to maintain if `ViewController` held an array of strings, which you used as your data model. When you delete a cell, you would remove the relevant item from the array. When you perform the segue, you pass in the appropriate element from the array to `FavouritesViewController`.

I'd be interested to see the rest of your code - how are you populating the cells? What happens to the cell values when you delete a row?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I'll add my deletion code right now.

Comment: OK, you're using core data. In that case, just pass the object along. Don't do anything with user defaults.

Comment: I have to use User defaults to save the views label to the device. It doesn’t have anything to do with the table view apart from it being its destination. Could I create different unique identifiers for each cell? If so, how could I look at doing that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Aren't you editing a "Favourite" here? Core data is there to save things "to the device", if you're using that, don't use defaults.

Comment: Okay, so basically on the first screen, I have a tableView so you can add, delete and access your favourite memories. Tapping on these cells will take it to its corresponsive view controller. I use defaults to save the text inside the title label which is in the cells view. I'm wondering if its possible to have every cell have their own identifier so that if i delete cell 2, then cell 3 moves up but keeps cell 3's original view.

Comment: Why not have the text as part of the core data entity that represents the favourite memory? Don't think of the identifier as belonging to the _cell_, that's your view. The identifier should live in your model.

Comment: I have managed to pass the cells name to the label in my memories view. But when I have multiple cells, the name is sometimes wrong. So if I tap "test 1" than the name test 1 appears on cell 1's view, and cell 2's. Until I tap another cell. Which then presents cell 2's name. So its like the name of the cell is behind by 1.